# IE 11 Permission denied for window.addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I need to add an event listener for window.open so that I can perform some actions when the window is closed.

```
var someWindow = window.open('https://some-url');
someWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() { // <- Permission Denied
    doSomething();
});
```

`window.onbeforeunload = function() { doSomething() }` neither throws the error nor it works.

This code works perfectly in Chrome. Even `console.log(window.addeventlistener)` throws the same error in IE 11.

Both the source & target URLs are HTTPS on different domains. The same problem also happens for localhost URLs.

Comment: There are a bunch of problems in your code. First IE11 does not support `const`. Then it is `addEventListener` not `addeventlistener`. The event name is `beforeunload` not `onbeforeunload`. I doubt this code ever worked in either browser due to code issues and same domain policy.

Comment: Neither browser would allow you to add event listener to a different domain window. The access is very limited https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Window

Comment: This is a react application with babel, so const works. Updated the spelling, I wrote the code from memory.

Comment: I did not find any article on browser support on this. And it works in Chrome.

Comment: Could you recreate a fiddle demonstrating it works in Chrome. Because I could not https://jsfiddle.net/tfgub7yk/7/ :) IE is the only browser that raises an exception (as it should be) instead of silently do nothing.